# What is an efficient way to conditionally process input batches of 5-20k docs into a collection with up to a million docs with mongodb / mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bigdata

In my mmo census / character stats tracking app I'm getting input batches with up to 5-20k documents each from the user, that I need to aggregate into the database. I have specific criteria to look for to decide if a document from the input is already present in the collection and needs to be updated or if it's completely new and needs to be inserted into the collection.

For my app to work properly it's also very important, that I can exactly determine, how many documents actually got updated and/or added directly after the input was processed.

*To better explain what I'm trying to do, I'm breaking it down to a simplified example where I can show you what the input looks like and what results are desired.*

---

As a starting point for the following input cases, this is how the collection looks like:

```
collection = [
  { name: 'Jean', server: 'Alpha', level: 9 },
  { name: 'Anna', server: 'Beta', level: 17 },
  { name: 'Jean', server: 'Beta', level: 10 }
];
```

From that there are basically 3 input cases that I need to cover.

---

**Case #1**

When I get an input with a completely new `name`+`server` combination, a new document should be added to the collection

```
input = { name: 'Victor', server: 'Alpha', level: 22 };
```

should become:

```
collection = [
  { name: 'Jean', server: 'Alpha', level: 9 },
  { name: 'Anna', server: 'Beta', level: 17 },
  { name: 'Jean', server: 'Beta', level: 10 },
  { name: 'Victor', server: 'Alpha', level: 22 }
];
```

**Case #2**

When I get an input with an existing `name`+`server` combination, but with a *higher* `level`, the existing document should be updated

```
input = { name: 'Jean', server: 'Alpha', level: 10 };
```

should become

```
collection = [
  { name: 'Jean', server: 'Alpha', level: 10 },
  { name: 'Anna', server: 'Beta', level: 17 },
  { name: 'Jean', server: 'Beta', level: 10 }
];
```

**Case #3**

When I get an input with an existing `name`+`server` combination, but with an *equal* or *lower* `level`, nothing should happen and the collection should stay how it was

```
input = { name: 'Jean', server: 'Alpha', level: 9 };
```

or

```
input = { name: 'Jean', server: 'Alpha', level: 8 };
```

should stay:

```
collection = [
  { name: 'Jean', server: 'Alpha', level: 9 },
  { name: 'Anna', server: 'Beta', level: 17 },
  { name: 'Jean', server: 'Beta', level: 10 }
];
```

---

What I'm doing so far is basically fetching the whole collection into an array and then use `Array.filter` to find out what inputs are already present in the collection and update them with `findOneAndUpdate`, and what inputs are new and insert them into the collection with `insertMany`:

```
Test.find({}, async (err, documents) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  if (documents.length > 0) {
    const changedInputs = inputs.filter(byChanged(documents));
    const newInputs = inputs.filter(byNew(documents));

    const insertResult = await Test.insertMany(newInputs);
    const inserted = insertResult.length;

    const updateResults = await Promise.all(compileUpdatePromises(changedInputs));
    let updated = 0;
    updateResults.forEach(updateResult => {
      updated = updateResult === 'updated' ? updated + 1 : updated;
    });

    console.log('updated:', updated);
    console.log('inserted:', inserted);
  }
});
```

[Link to a gist with the whole example](https://gist.github.com/christophrus/977e62dedbeaaf7b2e143ba7321bee2a/9985f0f05b737785cef38ef400014e63603ab3d4)

This worked fine when there weren't much documents in the collection, but now that it has grown to 50k+ documents it gets insanely slow and blocks the mongo connection during that process, what also blocks the whole api for all other calls.

Once this app gets more traffic it has the potential to quickly grow up to a collection of a million documents, that are then getting updated constantly.

Are there any easy and more efficient ways to let mongodb do all that hard work for me instead of doing it all by myself?

---

**Update 1:**

With the suggestions from **simagix** and **blackening** I got really close to a solution. This is what my changed code now looks like:

```
const bulkInput = inputs.map(input => ({
  updateOne: {
    filter: { name: input.name, server: input.server, level: { $lte: input.level } },
    upsert: true,
    update: { $set: { name: input.name, server: input.server, level: input.level } }
  }
}));

Test.bulkWrite(bulkInput).then(result => {
  console.log('inserted:', result.nUpserted, 'updated:', result.nModified);
});
```

The problem is now the 2nd example of **Case #3**:

```
input = { name: 'Jean', server: 'Alpha', level: 8 };
```

results in:

```
collection = [
  { name: 'Jean', server: 'Alpha', level: 9 },
  { name: 'Anna', server: 'Beta', level: 17 },
  { name: 'Jean', server: 'Beta', level: 10 },
  { name: 'Jean', server: 'Alpha', level: 8 }
];
```

[Link to updated gist](https://gist.github.com/christophrus/977e62dedbeaaf7b2e143ba7321bee2a/b118a7f703bfb9a986165002702ec8b9bf341627)

---

**Update 2:**

Just needed to make the compound index

```
testSchema.index({ name: 1, server: 1 });
```

to an unique compound index

```
testSchema.index({ name: 1, server: 1 }, { unique: true });
```

Now I have to find a proper solution for handling the `E11000 duplicate key error` exception that is throwing for **Case #3 example 2**.

[Link to updated gist](https://gist.github.com/christophrus/977e62dedbeaaf7b2e143ba7321bee2a)

Answer (score 1):

First, setup composite index. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/

Available on both mongodb and mongoose.

Second, please write proper retrieval queries. $or (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) when supported by index is O(k log n), where k is the number of matching items.

Alternatively, try the bulk operations. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/.

It can return the number of successful finds/updates. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/BulkWriteResult/. Add an extra field to find level: { $lt: currlvl } to do the updates only conditionally. I'm not particularly clear on how to combine this with upserts.

Finally, if i were you, i would hash/concat the server and name and make that the id. Would make life so much easier.

Comment: `bulkWrite` was a really great idea. I used that together with the suggestions from simagix  and updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

From your simplified example, the combination of *name* and *server* is unique.  You can create an unique index on `{name: 1, server: 1}`.  Use `updateOne` function to update and set `upsert` flag to true to insert the doc if a doc doesn't exists.  Below are commands from mongo shell to show you how it works.

```
db.records.drop()

db.records.createIndex({name:1, server:1})

db.records.insertMany([     
    { name: 'Jean', server: 'Alpha', level: 9 },        
    { name: 'Anna', server: 'Beta', level: 17 },        
    { name: 'Jean', server: 'Beta', level: 10 }  ])

db.records.find({}, {_id: 0})

db.records.updateOne(
    { name: 'Victor', server: 'Alpha', level: {$lte: 22} },     
    {$set: {name: 'Victor', server: 'Alpha', level: 22 }},      
    {upsert: true})

db.records.find({}, {_id: 0})

db.records.updateOne(
    { name: 'Jean', server: 'Alpha', level: {$lte: 9} }, 
    {$set: {name: 'Jean', server: 'Alpha', level: 9}}, 
    {upsert: 1})

db.records.find({}, {_id: 0})

db.records.updateOne(
    { name: 'Jean', server: 'Alpha', level: {$lte: 10} }, 
    {$set: {name: 'Jean', server: 'Alpha', level: 10 }}, 
    {upsert: 1})

db.records.find({}, {_id: 0})
```

Comment: Thats really nice, but now I'm stuck with the 2nd example of Case #3. `{ name: 'Jean', server: 'Alpha', level: {$lte: 8} }` doesn't match anything and upserts, what results in a duplicate document.

Comment: No, the unique index will prevent creating duplicates.

Comment: Oh I got ya. Just blindly copied your `createIndex({name:1, server:1})` that hadn't set the unique option. Now I only have to find a proper way to handle the `E11000 duplicate key error´ exception that is now throwing and then I'm done I guess. Thats genius, I really appreciate your help.